# Where to find the dynamic fields used on the email templates?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

I am super new on salesforce marketing cloud.

I created a template and it works great.

I am using the visual composer and it allows me to insert code into it, a previously person had added some dynamic fields such as `%%username%%`

Some others seems to be static like `%companyname%%`

when sending the email (someone else does), it replaces username and company name by the right values.

Using salesforce marketing cloud, how can I know where those fields were defined? (I want to change company name)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 different types of [personalization strings](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/)

1. Strings based off attributes inside of a list or data extension.  This is the basic variables, like 'First Name', 'Full Name', 'Order Number', etc. If you are referencing 'company name' as a variable for each person, this would be where to look - meaning you would need to change the value inside the list/data extension.
2. Strings based off account details - This is likely the one you are looking for.  This would include 'Company Name', 'Company Address', 'Unsubscribe link', etc.  To access/edit this information, you would need to go into the "administration' section of your account and select "Account Settings" here will list all the information, and there will be an 'edit' button towards the top to make these changes.
3. [Utility strings](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/): These include things like "Email Name", "Data Source", etc. These in general are super helpful, but not necessarily what you are looking for.

Outside of personalization strings, there is also [AMPScript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/), [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) and [GTL (Guide Template Language)](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/guide_template_language/) that can be used for dynamic content and personalization.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to the options available from the Personalization select menu:

[image: subscriber profile attributes]

These are subscriber profile attributes and can be created by selecting **Profile Management** from the Subscribers menu in the email app.

Click the **Create** button to create a new Attribute. If you select the **Hidden** option, this attribute will be supressed from the Profile Center page for the subscriber.

Note that a profile attribute value will need to exist (be added) to a Subscriber record in order for this value to be displayed in the email.